# Reset Hikvision camera through IP

Tags: camera, ip-camera

I have an IP camera and I can only access it through IP and password. Right now when I send it a snapshot request with my system I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> <ResponseStatus version="1.0" xmlns="urn:psialliance-org"> <requestURL>/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/101/picture</requestURL> <statusCode>3</statusCode> <statusString>Device Error</statusString> <subStatusCode>deviceError</subStatusCode> </ResponseStatus>:
```

Right now what I need is to reset that Camera, for example

- Model: Hikvision
- Vendor: NVR CH1
- IP: 10.70.25.1
- PORT: 8100
- user: shadmin
- Password: shadmin

How could I send some request to the camera to reset it? or is there any lists of commands which we can use with HTTP get post methods? Any lists for Hikvision CGI? and Onvif commands to reset the camera?

Any help will be thankful

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are doing the HTTP request wrong. 
To retrieve a snapshot, you can use this URL:

http://user:password@IP/Streaming/channels/**1**/picture

The number in **bold** identifies the channel you are getting the snapshot from. 
You can find in this link the download list from Hikvision, the one you are looking for is the
[Hikvision ISAPI(IP Surveillance Application Program Interface)](http://www.hikvision.com/en/download_83.html)

NOTE: You should be very carefull with any blank space in the PUT messages you send to the camera, as the camera do not trim the messages.

Answer (score 1):

use SADP tools to find and reset your IPcamera or NVR.
download it from below link :
https://www.hikvision.com/en/support/tools/hitools/clea8b3e4ea7da90a9/

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at `/ISAPI/System/factoryReset?mode=`

Method: `PUT`

Query:

mode: The recovery mode, which contains `full`, `basic`, and `part`
mode. The default mode is `full`, and all the device parameters will
be restored to default settings;​ for `basic` mode, the device
parameters, except network and user parameters, will be restored to
default settings;​ for `part` mode, only a part of default settings will
be restored.

Normally the authentication for interacting with hikvision cameras is `digest` or `basic`